# Pub/Sub - Publish without using an MQInput/Output - (IBM Integration Bus)

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

In a REST application, i need to publish a message in this flow:

RESTApi -> ComputeNode -> Publication -> ...

Can I publish without using an MQInput / Output? How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to set up the Properties tree to allow the Publication node to work without receiving the input message on MQ Input. MQ Output is not needed.

From the IIB knowledge center:

> The message being published must:
>
> Be a Publish command message
>
> Be a Delete Publication command message, or
>
> Have at least one topic present in the standard properties of the
>   message.

The 3rd option seems like the one you need.

Comment: How can i do it?